# Recursive rendering a collection in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, rendering, partial-views

I want to show comments tree. I moved comment div in another view, and wrote next line in `_comments.html.haml` :

```
= render :partial => 'single_comment', :collection => @post.comments.where(:parent_id => nil)
```

`_single_comments.html.haml`:

```
- if comment.id != nil
  .comment
    .meta
      = comment.name
      says
    .body
      = comment.text
  .answers
    = render :partial => 'posts/single_comment', :collection => @post.comments.where(:parent_id => comment.id)
```

But browser show me an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x00000004e39280>:0x00000004e2f398>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: - if comment.id != nil
2:   .comment
3:     .meta
4:       = comment.name
```

I tried to add `:as => comment` in first line, but it doesn't work. So as a using `@comment` in partial.
Maybe it's fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Either follow @Draiken's solution or change `comment` in partial to be `single_comment` as that is what the variable is named by convention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `:as => :comment` on both render lines, remember the answers that are being rendered are rendering this same partial again, so they will try rendering answers too.

Try adding the `:as => :comment` on both the comments and the answers rendering part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation:( I don't know how to earn it. I can't answer any questions yet:)